# `sudo yum update` throws Requires ... Removing ... Obsoleted By

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, amazon-linux

I'm on an Amazon Linux box:

```
# this command returns Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
cat /etc/system-release
```

When I try to `sudo yum update`, I get [this output](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/c57321eaae203bb92b09bc055291f910). I can't post the full output on SO but here is the part that bombs out:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: iproute-4.4.0-3.23.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Package: rpm-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: /usr/bin/db_stat
           Removing: db4-utils-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               Not found
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found
Error: Package: rpm-build-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: pam-1.1.8-12.33.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: libserf-1.3.7-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-python27-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby20-libs-2.0.0.648-2.40.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-libs-1.9.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: python26-2.6.9-2.92.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: sendmail-8.14.4-9.14.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-1.9.7-1.61.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: pam_ccreds-10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: apr-util-1.5.4-6.18.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: python27-libs-2.7.18-2.141.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-libs-4.11.3-40.78.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does anyone know how I can repair my `yum update` command? Any pointers would be very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha, I needed to:

```
sudo yum remove epel-release
sudo yum update
```